# Mongoose query not returning updated information with { new: true } param

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why is my query not returning updated information?

```
UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: userId },
            { $set: { couponList: couponList } }, { new: true }).populate('couponList').exec().then(user => {

            // user returning with the old information

        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I have 3 params:

- first one is the id of the user i want to update (objectId)
- second one is the information I want to update (objectId Array)
- third is the flag that says I want to receive the updated information (Boolean)

My coupon schema goes like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const CouponSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Unknown'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    validity: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    blackList: {
        type: Array,
        ref: 'user',
        default: []
    },
    blackListFlag: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    whiteList: {
        type: Array,
        ref: 'user',
        default: []
    },
    limit: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    counter: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    discountType: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined,
    }

},  { collection: 'coupon' });

export default mongoose.model('coupon', CouponSchema);
```

And in my user schema I have a ref to the coupon schema:

```
couponList : {
        type: Array,
        ref: 'coupon',
        default: []
    },
```

Comment: Can you please add your schema as well as what the couponList you are trying to update might look like?

Comment: 1) the `couponList` that You're passing must be array of `_id`-s from coupon collection. 2) are You sure that `UserSchema` takes an object `{_id: userId}` instead of just `findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $set: { couponList: couponList } }, { new: true })` ?  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found out that the problem was not with returning updated information but it was on populating the collection.**

The correct reference to the coupon collection in user schema:

```
couponList: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'coupon' } ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the field couponList in your schema.

**Edit**: Just noticed the UserSchema, theoretically, you should be fine, if you are pushing correct objectIds.

Comment: he already defined it, read under: `And on my user schema I have a ref to the coupon schema`

Answer (score 1):

`findByIdAndUpdate` with `{new: true}` must work as intended.

But I'm not aware of Your code totally and what kind of data You're sending as `couponList`.

So try to separate update and select operations and see what happens. In fact mongoose does the same when You call `findByIdAndUpdate`.

For example using express framework:

```
const User = mongoose.model('user');

router.put('/user/:userId/coupons', async (req, res) => {
  try {

   const {userId} = req.params;
   const {couponList} = req.body;

   await User.updateOne(
     {_id: userId}, 
     {$set: {couponList: couponList}}, 
     {upsert: false}
   );

   const user = await User
                        .findById(userId)
                        .populate('couponList').lean();

   res.status(200).send(user);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({})
  }
});
```

P.S. Only reason for that unexpected behavior may be that somehow (but it's not possible) it uses native driver for which `{new: true}` must be written as: `{returnNewDocument: true}`

[Check this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db.collection.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: in couponList I am saving the object id of the coupon as an array

Comment: Thy this: `{returnNewDocument: true}` instead of `{new: true}` may be conflict of drivers

Comment: nop, same result. The strange thing is that I have this exact same code working for a favorite list and it does return the updated information

Comment: @I'mnothuman I understand, but I always use update and select operations separately